# Flask Pdfkit- Unable to add custom font

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pdfkit, python-pdfkit

I'm trying to include my custom font, but I'm getting the following error indicating that the font is not found. However, I can confirm that I'm correctly pointing to the font directory.

```
OSError: wkhtmltopdf reported an error:
Loading pages (1/6)
[> ] 0%
[======> ] 10%
[==============================> ] 50%
Error: Failed to load file:///C:/Users/xxxxx/AppData/Local/Temp/cmunrm.ttf, with network status code 203 and http status code 0 - Error opening C:/Users/xxxxx/AppData/Local/Temp/cmunrm.ttf: No such file or
```

Code snippet of app.py

```
@app.route('/getDetails', methods=['POST'])
def x():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        path_wkhtmltopdf = 'static/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe'
        config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkhtmltopdf)
        rendered=render_template('resume.html',test='hi')
        cssPath=['static/css/resumeCss.css']
        pdf=pdfkit.from_string(rendered, False,configuration=config,css=cssPath)
        response=make_response(pdf)
        response.headers['Content-Type']='application/pdf'
        # response.headers['Content-Disposition']='attachment; filename=Print Me.pdf'
        response.headers['Content-Disposition']='inline'
        return response
```

resumeCss.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: myFirstFont;
  src: url('../fonts/cmunrm.ttf');
}
h1{
  font-family: myFirstFont;
}
```

I have also gone through the docs of wkhtmltopdf and have looked through the options but couldn't find an option to load a font there as well.